# laravel: command not found while trying to install laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install Laravel on a Raspberry Pi but I'm facing some problems after installing composer

Composer seems to be working fine as writing `composer` gives me the expected output with all possible commands.

According to Laravels own installation documentation i shall run the following command after i have installed Composer: `composer global require "laravel/installer"`, which seems to be working as no errors are shown. After this i need to add the `~/.composer/vendor/bin` path to my `$PATH` variable which i do and confirm by writing `echo $PATH` that gives me the following output: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/.composer/vendor/bin`

However running the `laravel` command afterwards just gives me `-bash: laravel: command not found`.

Can someone assist in what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

> export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a new project, using this command

```
laravel new project_name
```

You can use the Composer alternative

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name
```

You can find more info in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#installing-laravel).